# tree command line not working

Tags: tree, command, line

```
C:\>tree
'tree' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>
```

I try to type in tree in my command line and it does not recognize the command.  I am running Windows 10.  Anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

You may try adding the System32 folder (For example "`C:\Windows\System32`", or "`%SystemRoot%\System32`") to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

tree.com resides in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, but you probably have `%SystemRoot%\system32` in your `PATH` variable, else too much would not work.
As the extension is not `.exe`, I assume your `PATHEXT` environment variable is missing `.COM`.

Comment: I mean this should be moved to superuser.com.